# Jacobi symbol of sum of two squares

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, jacobi-symbol

Say we have $x=a^2+b^2$. Are there any results regarding the Jacobi symbol $(\frac{x}{n})$, where $n=p*q$? 
Having $x'=a^2+c^2$, is there any connection between the Jacobi symbols $(\frac{x}{n})$ and $(\frac{x'}{n})$?

Comment: I think the answer to both questions is "no" , even if $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes (which I assume)

Comment: Is there any particular reason for wanting $n$ to be a semiprime? Since the Jacobi symbol is just the product of Legendre symbols, it seems to me to make more sense to ask about $(\frac{x}{p})$ where $p$ is prime.

Comment: It's related to an encryption scheme.